# pulling data from another domain, react and api platform - symfony

Tags: reactjs, symfony, api-platform.com

Working locally, I'm trying to pull some data from an api endpoint into a react front-end. Here's what I have:-

Data source/api endpoint (api platform, symfony)

- `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users?page=1`

Front-end, React

- `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

**/src/App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users?page=1')
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .then(json => console.log(json))

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Firstly, I had to overcome a `CORS` issue with my data source. In symfony;-

**.env**

```
###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN='^https?://(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1)(:[0-9]+)?$'
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###
```

**As a side note**; For my api endpoint (data source) - I can return the json response fine using both `cURL` and `postman`. However, if I try directly in a browser address bar, I just get my api landing page back i.e. swagger doc.

[image]

I'm wondering if this is an issue with headers not being set?

Back in my `react` app `http://127.0.0.1:3000/` and at the console;-

[image]

my response is showing a 200 as you can see from above, but my `json` variable has a length of zero? So, no data.

Any ideas on how to pull the data (json) through to my react app using the above technique?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was looking for in the end...

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react'

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users?page=1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]